# Mars MOLA .csv layer in QGIS misplaced and very small

Tags: qgis, dem, csv

I'm trying to add Mars MOLA .csv data on top of CTX and HiRise DEMs but when I load them all up in QGIS the MOLA data is at a completely different location and very small in comparison. I downloaded the MOLA data from Mola PEDR Query and then edited it according to the CTX to MOLA section [here](http://lunokhod.org/?p=1417)
 
This is how my .csv table looks: 
[image]

Comment: Did you convert it to sinusoidal? Otherwise, I think it's still in lat/lon.

Comment: When I import it I choose the proj string: `+proj=sinu +lon_0=138 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=3396000 +b=3396000 +units=m +no_defs` which I took from the Lunokhod page that I linked above, though I don't know enough my self to know that it is right. Would importing it as sinu be the same as converting it to sinusoidal?